# DNS Rewrite Rules Apache To Ngnix Translation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I need you help i use to successfully migrate my site from Apache to Ngnix but i trying to convert some DNS rewrite rules and till now with no success . Can you please give me some translation help .

Rewrites that i wont to translate are :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net\.mk$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.net\.mk$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\.mk\/$1" [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.mk$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.mk$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\.mk\/$1[R=301,L]
```

Thanks for you support , where do a need to put translated rewrites in my vhost template or in nginx.conf (single web site on VPS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect a number of domains to another domain use a separate `server` block, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.net.mk www.domain.net.mk domain.mk www.domain.mk;
    return 301 http://domain.com.mk$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com.mk;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.